# gwpy package gives error - AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'FigureManagerBase' in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, pip, google-colaboratory

In Google Colab [gwpy](https://github.com/gwpy/gwpy) package giving error -

**AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'FigureManagerBase'**

(However, this same code is running all good in local machine ).

I already tried doing full uninstallation and then reinstalled [gwpy](https://github.com/gwpy/gwpy) fresh with below commands and restarted  (reset) the Colab's Machine. But error persists.

```
!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps gwpy

# And also the below ones
!pip install gwosc
!pip install dqsegdb2
!pip install ligotimegps
```

My Code, that uses the [gwpy](https://github.com/gwpy/gwpy) package is as below

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import signal

from gwpy.timeseries import TimeSeries
from gwpy.plot import Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')


def get_tseries_from_file(file_name):
  t_data = np.load(file_name)
  tseries1 = TimeSeries(t_data[0,:], sample_rate=2048)
  tseries2 = TimeSeries(t_data[1,:], sample_rate=2048)
  tseries3 = TimeSeries(t_data[2,:], sample_rate=2048)
  return tseries1, tseries2, tseries3

def plot_tseries(t1, t2, t3):
  plot = Plot(t1, t2, t3, separate=True, sharex=True, figsize=[20, 12])
  ax = plot.gca()
  ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
  ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]')
  plt.show()
  
file_1 = root_dir + 'train/0/0/0/000a5b6e5c.npy'
  
tseries1, tseries2, tseries3 = get_tseries_from_file(file_1)

# Plotting the 3 TimeSeries
plot_tseries(tseries1, tseries2, tseries3)
```

##### And getting the following error coming from `../gwpy/plot/plot.py`

**"module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'FigureManagerBase'"**

```
raceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gwpy/plot/plot.py in _init_figure(self, **kwargs)
    131         try:
--> 132             manager = backend_mod.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, self)
    133         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: module 'ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline' has no attribute 'new_figure_manager_given_figure'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gwpy/plot/plot.py in _init_figure(self, **kwargs)
    135                 pyplot.new_figure_manager.__module__)
    136             canvas = upstream_mod.FigureCanvasBase(self)
--> 137             manager = upstream_mod.FigureManagerBase(canvas, 1)
    138         manager._cidgcf = manager.canvas.mpl_connect(
    139             'button_press_event',

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'FigureManagerBase'
```

#### Additional Info

```py
print(matplotlib.get_backend()) # module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline
print(matplotlib.__version__) # 3.4.3
print(gwpy.__version__) # 2.0.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Source of Problem

In matplotlib 3.2.2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pyplot.new_figure_manager.__module__
```

yields: `matplotlib.backend_bases`

In matplotlib 3.4.3 it yields: `matplotlib.pyplot`

This is breaking:

##### Temporary workaround

As suggested in the [Tracking issue of gwpy](https://github.com/gwpy/gwpy/issues/1398) -

##### The temporary workaround for now in Colab is to use an earlier version of matplotlib-

```
!pip install matplotlib==3.2.2
```

With `3.2.2` it works fine.